# Flutter Overlay - detect a tap/click underneath and don't block it

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create an overlay above my app, so that the overlay can detect that a button was clicked in the app, but in the same time it won't block/consume it. Everything works as expected when I don't use Overlays. In this case i just use RawGestureDetector above the ElevatedButton and they both work fine.

When I try to do the same using an Overlay it no longer works. See the runnable code below:

When you run it and you switch to the second screen, only the "add one" button works. Clicks on other buttons are detected, even the mouse hovers are detected, but their handlers aren't run (even the back button in the AppBar is blocked).

Can it be fixed somehow?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const WithoutOverlay(title: 'Without Overlay'),
    );
  }
}




class WithoutOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  const WithoutOverlay({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<WithoutOverlay> createState() => _WithoutOverlayState();
}

class _WithoutOverlayState extends State<WithoutOverlay> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WithOverlay(title: "With Overlay")));
              },
              child: const Text("Show with overlay"),
            ),
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
            RawGestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
              gestures: {
                AllowMultipleTap: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<AllowMultipleTap>(
                  () => AllowMultipleTap(),
                  (AllowMultipleTap instance) {
                    instance.onTap = () => print('tap detected');
                  },
                )
              },
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                child: const Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



class WithOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  const WithOverlay({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<WithOverlay> createState() => _WithOverlayState();
}

class _WithOverlayState extends State<WithOverlay> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      final entry = OverlayEntry(
        builder: (context) {
          return RawGestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            gestures: {
              AllowMultipleTap: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<AllowMultipleTap>(
                () => AllowMultipleTap(),
                (AllowMultipleTap instance) {
                  instance.onTap = () => print('tap detected');
                },
              )
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                child: const Text("add one"),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );

      Overlay.of(context).insert(entry);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _incrementCounter,
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class AllowMultipleTap extends TapGestureRecognizer {
  @override
  void rejectGesture(int pointer) {
    acceptGesture(pointer);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a question, why not put the detect click function inside the buttons themselves without an overlay? With an overlay it would not only count the buttons clicked but also any tap all around the screen including empty spaces. So if a user is cleaning their phone screen for example, it may count as buttons clicked when that didnt actually happen

Comment: @Texv I could restrict the size of my RawGestureDetector just to some Button underneath so that I'd intercept clicks on that button only. I'd like to use it in something like an app tutorial, so that I know that user clicks where he's told to. I want to achieve it without requiring many changes in the base app's code like extra callbacks in buttons etc. I think I'll check using Stack instead of Overlays, maybe they will work better. But this question focuses on Overlays.

Answer (score 0):

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

OverlayEntry? overlayEntry;
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const WithoutOverlay(title: 'Without Home'),
    );
  }
}

class WithoutOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  const WithoutOverlay({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<WithoutOverlay> createState() => _WithoutOverlayState();
}

class _WithoutOverlayState extends State<WithoutOverlay> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (didPop) async {
        debugPrint("Will pop");
        overlayEntry?.remove();
        overlayEntry?.dispose();
        overlayEntry = null;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const WithOverlay(title: "With Overlay")));
                  overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 200),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                spreadRadius: 5,
                                blurRadius: 7,
                                offset: const Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: const WithOverlay(title: "With Overlay"));
                    },
                  );

                  Overlay.of(context).insert(overlayEntry!);
                },
                child: const Text("Show with overlay"),
              ),
              const Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
              ),
              RawGestureDetector(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                gestures: {
                  AllowMultipleTap: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<AllowMultipleTap>(
                    () => AllowMultipleTap(),
                    (AllowMultipleTap instance) {
                      instance.onTap = () => print('tap detected');
                    },
                  )
                },
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WithOverlay extends StatefulWidget {
  const WithOverlay({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<WithOverlay> createState() => _WithOverlayState();
}

class _WithOverlayState extends State<WithOverlay> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
    //   final entry = OverlayEntry(
    //     builder: (context) {
    //       return RawGestureDetector(
    //         behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
    //         gestures: {
    //           AllowMultipleTap: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<AllowMultipleTap>(
    //             () => AllowMultipleTap(),
    //             (AllowMultipleTap instance) {
    //               instance.onTap = () => print('tap detected');
    //             },
    //           )
    //         },
    //         child: Container(
    //           width: 100,
    //           height: 100,
    //           color: Colors.red,
    //           alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    //           child: ElevatedButton(
    //             onPressed: _incrementCounter,
    //             child: const Text("add one"),
    //           ),
    //         ),
    //       );
    //     },
    //   );

    //   Overlay.of(context).insert(entry);
    // });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
        leading: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            debugPrint("Will pop");
            overlayEntry?.remove();
            overlayEntry?.dispose();
            overlayEntry = null;
          },
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.navigate_before_rounded,
            size: 30,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _incrementCounter,
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AllowMultipleTap extends TapGestureRecognizer {
  @override
  void rejectGesture(int pointer) {
    acceptGesture(pointer);
  }
}
```

I think the problem is that you don't really understand how to use it. Here is the demo code I made, you can refer to it.
Docs overlay: [enter link description here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html)

Comment: We might have a misunderstanding here. I used two screens to demonstrate that the first one works, and the other doesn't. It's not that I want one screen above the other like in your example. Imagine I want some overlay above some screen which don't control too much - maybe I just have a GlobalKey to its widget. And I want an overlay to hide some portions of that screen and detect that user clicks on some other (visible) portions.